# Bootstrap carousel not working rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to integrate bootstrap's carousel in my ruby on rails application, so i made this view :

```
<head>
</head>
  <body>
 <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
      <!--<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>-->
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="<%= image_url('lol.jpg')%>" alt="Leagues Of Legends">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="<%= image_url('SC2.jpg')%>" alt="Starcraft II">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span >
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </body>
```

It does display a carousel, with my first image and everything.

**The problem is that nothing else works : the prev button, the next button and even the little dots does nothing when clicked on**

I don't know if this a related to my code (doubt it thought i have tested plenty others and still the same) or to rails itself ...

Any help is welcome !

EDIT

this is my assets/javascript/application.js file :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: are you sure already load required bootstrap javascript file?

Comment: @SaiqulHaq Not sure what you're refering to, but i did add import "bootstrap-sprockets" and import "bootstrap" (with the @) to my aplication.css.sass, did i miss anything ?

Comment: edit your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file
then add

//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets;

please refer the docs first, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Yeah i did that already (sorry about that), i'll edit my post to add my application.js file

Comment: it seems your html code not included css and javascript files, the head tag is empty, and there is no rails include javascript code in body tag

Comment: Hum i assumed that those files where included by default in a rails application isn't that the case ?

Comment: you have to call this method in your head html  tags -> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag

Comment: I added javascript_include_tag "application.js" in the <head> tag, but it doesn't seem to do the trick :/

Comment: Open developer console in the browser, and check, make sure there are no any errors

Comment: Tried that, sadly no errors are showing..

Comment: Does your application CSS file have the .SASS extension (it's stated in your comment above) because it should be .SCSS (aplication.css.scss). And application.js should only have one Bootstrap file required in it, not both.

Comment: @vanburenx Yes my application css does have the sass extension, i read it was usual for bootstrap integration in rails. anyway i tried puting it back to .scss and it simply disable bootstrap at all ^^. I did remove the require bootstrap in application.js thought, but doesn't work either .. But thx for advice !

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the javascript and jquery in your code for this carousel to work.

In the end of your html file, add this (it can be between the div and body)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
  $('#mycarousel').carousel();
  });
</script>
```

It should do the trick.
You can also put this code on a partial and load it on your application layout.